# Selecting checkboxes within a div

Tags: jquery, html

This should be simple but can't get it to work. For now I am trying to see if my checkboxes within the inputs are registering as being checked. Here's my code. Sorry if this is a very dumb question. When I **click/check** them, there's no logging statement. Thanks

```
<div class="style">
    <label> Test </label>
    <div class="fields quad">
        <div class="field inline">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="business_brand_colors_yellow" name="brand_colors_yellow" data-bind="checked: business().brand_colors_yellow" value="yellow">
                </div>
                <label for="business_brand_colors_yellow"><?=l(184)?></label>
            </div>
            <div class="swatches">
                <div class="swatch" style="background-color: #f0f01a"></div>
                <div class="swatch" style="background-color: #f2f792"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field inline">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="business_brand_colors_orange" name="brand_colors_orange" data-bind="checked: business().brand_colors_orange" value="orange">
                </div>
                <label for="business_brand_colors_orange"><?=l(185)?></label>
            </div>
            <div class="swatches">
                <div class="swatch" style="background-color: #db4f1d"></div>
                <div class="swatch" style="background-color: #f57133"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   //JQuery
    var $colorPalCB = $('.style').find('checkbox');

    if (($colorPalCB).is(':checked')) {
    console.log('checked')
   }
```

Comment: You either need to query for the ID or Class of the checkbox elements or use an attribute selector, i.e. `$('.style').find('[type="checkbox"]');`

Comment: There is no logging because there are no event handlers. Your check runs once, on page load, and that is it.

Comment: You need to update your knowledge. Read about **event handling** in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help and suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use the hard and indirect way?
You can use the following selector and code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
        if ($(this).prop('checked')){
          console.log("checked");
        }
        else{
          console.log("Unchecked")
        }
      })
    })
  </script>
```

Checkout [**this DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/tulocenepe/edit?html,console,output)

On the other hand, I could find the following, *two*, main limitations in your code:

1. It does not deal with any event related to the element.
2. The find result should be an array of elements.

Comment: Docs for `.change`: https://api.jquery.com/change/. It is equivalent to `.on("change", function(){ … })`.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Yes you are right and `.on("event",...` may be obligatory used if the element dynamically created or loaded (via AJAX for example)